# kubectl patch statefulset updateStrategy RollingUpdate NOT patched

Tags: kubernetes

I am unable to patch my statefulset to use a `RollingUpdate` strategy.

(Encountered while working through the "StatefulSet Basics" tutorial [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#rolling-update))

```
$ kubectl patch statefulset web -p '{"spec":{"strategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate"}}}' 
statefulset "web" not patched
```

I wish `kubectl patch` would return more info as to the reason the statefulset could not be patched.

`kubectl edit` tells me...

> found invalid field updateStrategy for v1beta1.StatefulSetSpec

But I am not sure I put the key and value in the proper place to be sure this is the same issue `patch` is encountering.

How do tell my statefulset to use a RollingUpdate strategy?

To reproduce this issue just follow the Kubernetes tutorial here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/

Comment: You are running kubernetes 1.7? Else this will not work.

Comment: Oh...   i'm running v1.6.4  :/

Comment: The patch should be: `'{"spec":{"updateStrategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate"}}}'`

Answer (score 1):

Better to apply changes on your yaml file directly.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-sts
spec:
  serviceName: "nginx-headless"
  replicas: 3
  #podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx-sts-demo
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0   #for full partition update            
    type: RollingUpdate
```